# django-tenat and rest_framework_simplejwt integration, error in blacklisting a token

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, django-tenants

I am using `django-tenent` and `rest_framework_simplejwt` and i had no any issue until I implemented `rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist` then it started to give me errors like:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "token_blacklist_outstandingtoken" violates foreign key constraint "token_blacklist_outs_user_id_83bc629a_fk_authusers"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1b87717c-e91e-4049-8e89-5db9dbef4015) is not present in table "authusers_customuser".
```

Project configuration 
In `settings.py`

```
SHARED_APPS = (
    'django_tenants',
    'tenants.apps.TenantsConfig',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'authusers.apps.AuthusersConfig',

    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
)

TENANT_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'authusers.apps.AuthusersConfig',
    ... # my apps
)
```

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "NON_FIELD_ERROR_KEY": "error",
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
    ),
}

# Rest-restframework jwt validation token lifetime
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "authusers.serializers.CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer",
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(hours=12),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=3),
}
```

I am using all the things provided by package for login, refresh, verify in `urls.py`

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenRefreshView, TokenBlacklistView, TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenVerifyView
)

path('login/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
path('token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
```

All was going smoothly until i added `'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist'` in `SHARED_APP` then it asked for migration which i migrated then i tried logging, it started to show above error message.

I did some research a found this [issue](https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants/issues/759) in github and tried installing in `TENENT_APP` still had the same issue.

I am like confused why is the sub-domain isn't redirecting the blacklist token to the correct schema. I am using single db multiple schema, all the request are being redirected to the correct schema on the database except those urls. Now all those are using public tenant db to look for user and perform action.

What i am assuming from the error above is that while performing those actions package is now looking in correct schema even though i have used sub-domain url for logging in.